# How to add a page which inherits from automatic authentication in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

I am using an automatically created authentication in ASP.net MVC,I chose  Individual User Accounts while I was creating the website. I also have some models and I created controllers and views again automatically with an option called "MVC 5 Controllers with views, using EntityFramework". My problem is, I can have access to the controllers directly without logging into the website and I need the authentication for those views as well. Do I need to add some lines of code like:

```
public class myclass : IdentityUser {}
```

anything in controllers ?

Comment: [Security, Authorization and Authentication](https://www.asp.net/mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication is enforced via the `[Authorize]` attribute. You place this attribute on your controller class or actions.

A quick and easy way to add authentication to all your views is to register the authorize attribute globally. You can do this in `FilterConfig` class like this:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Then in Global.asax.cs `Application_Start()` you call it like this:
`FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);`

Now every controller will require authentication. If you need to allow anonymous access to a particular controller or action you can add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.